# Why sshxcute library returns error intermittently when tries to run Result class?

Tags: java, ssh

I developed a Java application can connect to an IP address, run several scripts and return results, in Linux environment. I used sshxcute library for this task, it works perfectly But intermittently stuck when the sshxcute command try to return result, the only way to wraparound is force the sshxcute to close ssh manually and lost the result.
What is wrong with my code?
I guess sshexcute has problem to run Result class.

This is one of the methods used:

```
private void sshcopyimage(SSHExec ssh) {
    try {

        // Create a ExecCommand, the reference class must be
        // CustomTask

        CustomTask ct3 = new ExecCommand("cd /screenShots",
                "ls -tr | tail -1");

        Result res3 = ssh.exec(ct3);
        //The application stuck in this line intermittently.  
        filename = res3.sysout;

        // Check result and print out messages.
        if (res3.isSuccess) {
            System.out.println("Return code: " + res3.rc);
            System.out.println("sysout: " + res3.sysout);
            output.setText("file name gotten.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Return code: " + res3.rc);
            System.out.println("error message: " + res3.error_msg);
            output.setText("Error in getting the file name .");
        }
    } catch (TaskExecFailException e5) {
        MyMessage.infoBox(e5.getMessage(), "Error");
        output.setText("Error.");
        System.out.println(e5.getMessage());
        e5.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e6) {
        MyMessage.infoBox(e6.getMessage(), "Error");
        output.setText("Error.");
        System.out.println(e6.getMessage());
        e6.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        //MyMessage.infoBox("Picture created.", "Message");
        output.setText("Picture created.");
        bashcommand();
    }
}
```

more similar methods used in this app and all of them stuck in the same line intermittently 1/30.

Comment: Try jssh: http://www.pitman.co.za/projects/jssh/

Comment: Can you be more specific about your problem and requirements? - otherwise it seems to be asking for recommendations and could be viewed as primarily opinion based which is off topic as per the help: [help/on-topic]

Comment: Matt Coubrough, I changed the title and edited the content, hope it meets the website policy. if not let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found my answer.
I replaced excute library by JSCH and works perfectly.
It was good for me to find my answer by myself :)